# IEEE submission issue

Tags: latex, tex, ieee

I create a Latex dvipdf in overleaf, where everything works fine and the pdf produced looks ok. All images are *.eps (IEEE requirement).
When I upload all files to IEEE portal, the pdf produced has ONLY two pics misplaced like the following:

[image]

Problem is I don't know where to look or what to change.
The code used is very standard:

```
\begin{figure}[!pt]
\centering
\subfloat[Initial graph setup]
{\includegraphics[width\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a1.eps}
\label{fig:dodagBef}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Mobility issue]   {\includegraphics[width=0.24   
\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a2.eps}\label{fig:dodagAft}}
\caption{DODAG's setup example}
\end{figure}
```

I added the keepaspectratio which made no difference. I also played with [!pt], [!ht].
I am guessing it has to do something with dvi?

Comment: Where is the closing ']' for the \subfloat on line 3?

Comment: it is in the next line {fig:dodagAft}}

Comment: No it isn't. that is the closing square bracket from the \include graphics. Count your left square braces and right square braces in your code snippet. Or compare your two subfloat lines the second one has a closing square before the {\includegraphics...}

Comment: I know that Latex/Tex is most on-topic here, but there is also [tex.se] - you might get a better answer there next time

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a square brace in your first subfloat command.

```
\begin{figure}[!pt]
\centering
\subfloat[Initial graph setup] %%this bracket was missing
{\includegraphics[width\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a1.eps}
\label{fig:dodagBef}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Mobility issue]   {\includegraphics[width=0.24   
\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a2.eps}\label{fig:dodagAft}}
\caption{DODAG's setup example}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right :-} It was a copy & paste error... I just corrected the original post so it will not confuse people. Yet the problem remains...